# Entity Framework Core 2.1 group by not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity framework Core 2.1.4 and I wrote an basic example query from C# like below.

```
var myList = context.HastaAdres.OrderBy(p => p.ID).Take(20).GroupBy(p => p.IlKodu).Select(d => d.FirstOrDefault()).Select(p => p.ID).ToList();
```

But in SQL profiler, running code like below. **There is no group by in SQL and very different from classic entity framework. So, also result is different. I need only one column as a result. But first query, return all columns. Also row count is different from second query.**

**SQL Generated By Entity framework Core**

```
SELECT [t].[ID], [t].[IlKodu], [t].[AcikAdres], [t].[BucakAdi], [t].[BucakKodu], [t].[BulvarKodu], [t].[CaddeKodu], [t].[CreatedBy], [t].[CreatedDate]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(20) [p].[ID], [p].[IlKodu], [p].[AcikAdres], [p].[BucakAdi], [p].[BucakKodu], [p].[BulvarKodu], [p].[CaddeKodu], [p].[CreatedBy], [p].[CreatedDate]
    FROM [Ortak].[HastaAdres] AS [p]
    ORDER BY [p].[ID]
) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[IlKodu]
```

When I tried this method in Entity Framework, it's generating perfect code.

**SQL Generated By Entity framework**

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Limit2].[ID] AS [ID]
        FROM ( SELECT TOP (20) [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID], [Extent2].[IlKodu] AS [IlKodu]
            FROM [Ortak].[HastaAdres] AS [Extent2]
            ORDER BY [Extent2].[ID] ASC
        )  AS [Limit2]
        WHERE ([Distinct1].[IlKodu] = [Limit2].[IlKodu]) OR (([Distinct1].[IlKodu] IS NULL) AND ([Limit2].[IlKodu] IS NULL))) AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT [distinct].[IlKodu] AS [IlKodu]
        FROM ( SELECT TOP (20) 
            [Extent1].[IlKodu] AS [IlKodu]
            FROM [Ortak].[HastaAdres] AS [Extent1]
            ORDER BY [Extent1].[ID] ASC
        )  AS [distinct]
    )  AS [Distinct1]
```

What can be the reason of this situation?

Comment: Are you getting the correct data? EF6 and EFCore are very different products and it's not surprising they generate different SQL.

Comment: No, data is different. Because first one isn't applying groupby. And I need one column but entity framework return all columns.

Comment: Instead of `.Select(d => d.FirstOrDefault())` you can use `SelectMany`

Comment: @DavidG is asking  about the *materialized* result (in `myList`), not the SQL query. EF Core uses mixed approach, so the actual result != SQL query

Comment: Thanks @stoev. Yes result in C# the same. But this is very big problem for me. Because this will cause big performance problem. Second query return ten seconds. But first one is ten minute.

Comment: I see. That's a different story and unfortunately EF Core still can't translate many constructs to SQL and evaluates them locally. It's strange though - even with client evaluation taking 20 records should not take 10 min. What if you pre-select the fields that you need, e.g. `context.HastaAdres.Select(p => new { p.ID, p.IlKodu }).OrderBy(…)...`?

Comment: In my real scenario there was 70 columns with big data and more than 200.000.000 data. So, it took very long time getting all columns instead of one columns. But, I don't understand, why Microsoft changed its starategy as local operation. Is there any logic for this ? And how can I write my query in EF Core without local groupBy. Because, this query time not acceptable for my application. @IvanStoev

Comment: @realist Why? I guess the usual factors - schedule, lack of time / resources. It's not final - improving over the time, probably will be optimized some day. The problem is that this is how it is now. Unfortunately I see no way to let them generate the desired SQL query. Have you tried my suggesting - pre select the 2 fields, then do order by and take - this should limit the SQL query to 20 records with 2 fields.

Comment: It's as @IvanStoev said. EF Core still can't translate Linq `GroupBy` to `SQL GroubBy`. They just added "some" translations if you use aggregation function like `Sum`. You can check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation.

Comment: As to solve your issue, you can just write your own query using `context.HastaAdres.FromSql`, using whatever you need to make it performant.

Comment: Thank you for your help @IvanStoev and jpgrassi. I understand that, I'm gonna have to write a different query.I hope most recently, Microsoft supports SQL groupBy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I learnt that EF Core not supporting database level Group By and take element. But, by EF Core 2.1, came support for group by then sum,min,max,average at databse level.(You can see from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation from commented by @jpgrassi)

So, I changed my query code as take min value and then get that row from database. So, this solved my isuue. But, I hope, most recent time, Microsoft supports group by at database level.